# WPF Data Grid how to add text boxes and other custom controls dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to create a `DataGrid` in WPF and i want to add text box controls and check boxes to the grid dynamically . I want to set the string values to text boxes dynamically at run time. Can anyone provide me a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I wrote [Create DataGrid in WPF using code](http://harishasanblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/create-datagrid-in-wpf-using-code.html) take a look at it

Comment: Don't just link off-site, links die.